# Delete listbox item

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a Windows Forms application with two listboxes and a delete button. The first listbox displays a foodmenu, quantity and totalprice and the second one displays the totalprice.

When I click the delete button I want the item selected in the first listbox to be deleted in both listboxes. But the item is only deleted from the first listbox.

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove (ListBox1.Selected.Item)
ListBox2.Items.Remove (ListBox1.Selected.Item)
```

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify your question?

Comment: What is MCVE? I don't what MCVE is...

Comment: That's a link to the help page explaining exactly that

Answer (score 1):

You should read your code thoroughly before posting here.

```
ListBox2.Items.Remove (ListBox1.Selected.Item)
```

Tries to delete the selected item in **ListBox1** from **ListBox2**. Since `ListBox2` does not contain the very item it cannot be removed.